# Unable to access to internet on ubuntu machine connected to windows machine using Ethernet

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ethernet, gateway

I have connected my rasberry pi running Ubuntu 20.04 using Ethernet to my Windows laptop. I have set static IP and subnet mask of Ethernet port on Windows laptop as follows:

[image]

I have enabled Internet sharing on Windows laptop:

[image]

I have set static IP on my raspberry pi too:

```
# ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.137.50  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.137.255
        ether 18:9b:a5:40:5d:59  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 203  bytes 22521 (22.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 234  bytes 12036 (12.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I am able to ping Windows laptop from Raspberry pi:

```
# ping 192.168.137.1
PING 192.168.137.1 (192.168.137.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=2.061 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=5.545 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.137.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=1.805 ms
^C--- 192.168.137.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.805/3.137/5.545/1.706 ms
```

Also I am able to ping raspberry pi from Windows laptop:

```
>ping 192.168.137.50

Pinging 192.168.137.50 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.137.50: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.50: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.137.50: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.137.50:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 2ms
```

I am able to ping google from windows laptop:

```
>ping google.com

Pinging google.com [172.217.166.46] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.217.166.46: bytes=32 time=31ms TTL=58
Reply from 172.217.166.46: bytes=32 time=14ms TTL=58
Reply from 172.217.166.46: bytes=32 time=20ms TTL=58

Ping statistics for 172.217.166.46:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 14ms, Maximum = 31ms, Average = 21ms
```

But I am unable to ping google from raspberry pi:

```
# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.166.46): 56 data bytes
^C92 bytes from 192.168.137.50: Destination Host Unreachable
--- google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

What I am missing here?

PS:

Below are outputs of some commands which might be useful:

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by resolvconf
domain mshome.net
nameserver 127.0.0.1

# route -ne
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U         0 0          0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.137.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.137.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.225.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 bridge0
```

Comment: Probably because of the first route you shown above. Find out what added that. (If it was added directly by you, just remove it.)